# long complicated string into json or dictionary

Tags: python, json

Is it possible to convert the following `string` into a dictionary or `json` object:

> {"created_at": "Thu Feb 19 11:28:52 +0000 2009", "description": "Le
>   p\u00f4le de comp\u00e9titivit\u00e9 de la fili\u00e8re des contenus
>   et services num\u00e9riques. http://www.capdigital.com //
>   http://www.facebook.com/capdigitalparisregion", "favourites_count": 7,
>   "followers_count": 5996, "friends_count": 671, "geo_enabled": true,
>   "id": 21290877, "lang": "en", "listed_count": 344, "location":
>   "Paris", "name": "Cap Digital", "profile_background_color": "920707",
>   "profile_background_tile": true, "profile_image_url":
>   "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2263411541/cap_square_normal.png",
>   "profile_link_color": "0084B4", "profile_sidebar_fill_color":
>   "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/157539330/xad3a63c73eff9ba8f89f81e01c10a4d.jpg",
>   "profile_text_color": "333333", "protected": false, "screen_name":
>   "Cap_Digital", "status": {"created_at": "Mon Mar 18 16:23:05 +0000
>   2013", "favorited": false, "id": 313687008188956672, "retweet_count":
>   5, "retweeted": false, "source": "http://clocktweets.com/\"
>   rel=\"nofollow\">Clocktweets", "text": "Plus que quelques jours
>   avant @5Plus_Forum, conf\u00e9rence sur la ville intelligente !
>   http://t.co/GV5o6fiqUh", "truncated": false}, "statuses_count": 2121,
>   "time_zone": "Paris", "url": "http://www.capdigital.com",
>   "utc_offset": 3600}

I tried `json.load()` it gives the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\schatterjee\workspace\twittermining\main.py", line 82, in <module>
    treat_files()      
  File "C:\Users\schatterjee\workspace\twittermining\main.py", line 74, in treat_files
    d = json.load(row[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 274, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: You should use json.loads() for loading strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `json.loads()` (with an `s` for "string") rather than `json.load()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in the string that you presented the modified string is parsed correctly as JSON

```py
{'created_at': 'Thu Feb 19 11:28:52 +0000 2009',
 'description': 'Le p\\u00f4le de comp\\u00e9titivit\\u00e9 de la fili\\u00e8re des contenus et services num\\u00e9riques. http://www.capdigital.com // http://www.facebook.com/capdigitalparisregion',
 'favourites_count': 7,
 'followers_count': 5996,
 'friends_count': 671,
 'geo_enabled': True,
 'id': 21290877,
 'lang': 'en',
 'listed_count': 344,
 'location': 'Paris',
 'name': 'Cap Digital',
 'profile_background_color': '920707',
 'profile_background_tile': True,
 'profile_image_url': 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2263411541/cap_square_normal.png',
 'profile_link_color': '0084B4',
 'profile_sidebar_fill_color': 'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/157539330/xad3a63c73eff9ba8f89f81e01c10a4d.jpg',
 'profile_text_color': '333333',
 'protected': False,
 'screen_name': 'Cap_Digital',
 'status': {'created_at': 'Mon Mar 18 16:23:05 +0000 2013',
            'favorited': False,
            'id': 313687008188956672L,
            rel=\\"nofollow\\">Clocktweets", # here
            'retweet_count': 5,
            'retweeted': False,
            'source': 'http://clocktweets.com/\\',
            'text': 'Plus que quelques jours avant @5Plus_Forum, conf\\u00e9rence sur la ville intelligente ! http://t.co/GV5o6fiqUh',
            'truncated': False},
 'statuses_count': 2121,
 'time_zone': 'Paris',
 'url': 'http://www.capdigital.com',
 'utc_offset': 3600}
```

Comment: @codious Check the string you have posted, `ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 1013 (char 1013)`

Comment: @Schoolboy: If you're pasting the string into your source code, you need to include it as a raw string: `r"""etc etc"""`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to a file-like buffer first:

```
json.load(StringIO.StringIO(your_string))
```

Comment: One can use json.loads instead